# How to cut an irregular shape into 2 congruent parts

Tags: geometry, congruences-geometry

Is it possible to cut this shape:

[image]

into 2 congruent parts (equal area and shape).

The guy who gave us this teaser said that it's possible. But i can't for the life of me figure out how.

In the figure, $ABCD$ is a square, angle $CDE$ is a right angle, and the curve $AE$ is a circular arc with center $C$.

Comment: Do you mean to divide it into two equal parts with a single straight line?

Comment: Doesn't have to be a straight line. Any single cut from one side to another that divides it into 2 congruent shapes will do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

(This space intentionally left blank.)

Comment: Ah, i can't believe i didn't look at it like that yet... it has rotational symmetry. Thank you very much!

Comment: What software did you use to make this image?

Comment: @orlp: [GeoGebra](https://geogebra.com)